# Altair limit number of bars

Tags: python, altair

Suppose that I have a dataframe like this one

```
   label  counts
4      4       8
5      5       7
6      6       6
7      7       5
0      0       4
1      1       3
2      2       2
3      3       1
```

I want to make a bar chart with altair, where the height of the bars is counts, and the label is the label. How do I limit the number of bars to be shown, if I want the top 3 counts?

I know I can make `df.sort_values("counts", ascending=False).iloc[:3]` to be the source of the chart, but I was wondering if there is a way of doing this directly with altair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this following the [Top K Items](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/top_k_items.html) example from the Altair documentation. Here it is applied to your data:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
   label  counts
4      4       8
5      5       7
6      6       6
7      7       5
0      0       4
1      1       3
2      2       2
3      3       1
"""), delim_whitespace=True)

alt.Chart(df).transform_window(
    rank='rank(counts)',
    sort=[alt.SortField('counts', order='descending')]
).transform_filter(
    alt.datum.rank <= 3
).mark_bar().encode(
    x='counts:Q',
    y='label:O'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp Will this hold if I facet the chart? If I have another column, say group, where the first 4 rows are from group 1 and the second 4 rows are from group 2, if I add a facet by the variable group, will I still be showing top 3 labels per group?

Comment: No, you'll have to modify it slightly, I think,

Comment: I haven't been able to do that with altair nor seaborn. If you know how to do it, do you want me to create another question or could you expand your answer in this question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another question would be best. Code blocks don’t render in comment threads.

Comment: I opened [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65801275/4107770)